# How do I remove all the buttons on the console application?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Im trying to remove all the buttons on the console application (minimise, maximise, and close) however cant find anything online thats useful. I tried this code which i converted from C# but it didnt work either:

```
Class Program
        Private Const MF_BYCOMMAND As Integer = &H0
        Public Const SC_CLOSE As Integer = &HF060
        <DllImport("user32.dll")>
        Public Shared Function DeleteMenu(ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal nPosition As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll")>
        Private Shared Function GetSystemMenu(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal bRevert As Boolean) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
        Private Shared Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr
        End Function

        Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), False), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND)
            Console.Read()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

And this class to your code file:

```
Public Class HelperClass
Const WS_BORDER As Integer = 8388608
Const WS_DLGFRAME As Integer = 4194304
Const WS_CAPTION As Integer = WS_BORDER Or WS_DLGFRAME
Const WS_SYSMENU As Integer = 524288
Const WS_THICKFRAME As Integer = 262144
Const WS_MINIMIZE As Integer = 536870912
Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX As Integer = 65536
Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16
Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Integer = -20
Const WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME As Integer = &H1
Const SWP_NOMOVE As Integer = &H2
Const SWP_NOSIZE As Integer = &H1
Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED As Integer = &H20

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=False)>
Private Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=False)>
Private Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=False)>
Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
Public Shared Sub MakeExternalWindowBorderless(ByVal MainWindowHandle As IntPtr)
    Dim Style As Integer = 0
    Style = GetWindowLong(MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE)
    Style = Style And Not WS_CAPTION
    Style = Style And Not WS_SYSMENU
    Style = Style And Not WS_THICKFRAME
    Style = Style And Not WS_MINIMIZE
    Style = Style And Not WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    SetWindowLong(MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, Style)
    Style = GetWindowLong(MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    SetWindowLong(MainWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style Or WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME)
    SetWindowPos(MainWindowHandle, New IntPtr(0), 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_FRAMECHANGED)
End Sub
End Class
```

Next in your main method add this:

```
HelperClass.MakeExternalWindowBorderless(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
Console.Read()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i was unable to make it work, do i have to call something or should it do it it on its own? (sorry fotr the dumb questions, this is a little advanced for me)

Comment: No problem :) If you have a module go to its main sub of the module and type in this: `MakeExternalWindowBorderless(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)` and to see the results add this line as well: `Console.Read()`

Comment: Im placing this command in sub main and get an error : 'MakeExternalWindowBorderless' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I would attach an image but i cannot

Comment: I have updated my answer, it is working for me, so if it is not working for you than it may be something on your computer.

Comment: Didnt work unfortunately :( Probably an isuue on my side even though i tried to run it in a new program. Any idea what version of visual studio you are using?